# How can I access and on requests library

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I tried to access to https://twitter.com by requests library to create a web scraping project, I imported Requests and wrote

```
r = requests.get("https://twitter.com")
```

but I didn't get any response to start. **Twitter is blocked in Iran.**

Is it possible to work with a blocked site by requests?

Comment: If you can, use a VPN or Tor to access sites that are blocked. (Of course, this means that the VPN itself is not blocked.)

Comment: Does VPN go on even on Visual Studio Code or PyCharm?

Comment: The VPN software configures your operating system to allow your computer to connect to web sites and networks outside of your own country's network. Unfortunately, a VPN usually requires a subscription. However, Tor is free and could allow you access outside of Iran (but Tor can be slow.)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer because the question is answered in the comments by Tom.

Is it possible to work with a blocked site by requests?

> If you can, use a VPN or Tor to access sites that are blocked. (Of
> course, this means that the VPN itself is not blocked.)

Does VPN go on even on Visual Studio Code or PyCharm?

> The VPN software configures your operating system to allow your
> computer to connect to web sites and networks outside of your own
> country's network. Unfortunately, a VPN usually requires a
> subscription. However, Tor is free and could allow you access outside
> of Iran (but Tor can be slow.)

If you want to try tor, check out https://www.torproject.org/. If VPN, I recommend using the free plan at https://protonvpn.com/.